# Truck fleet monitoring project

Tags: obd-ii, sensor, truck, can-bus, scan-tool

I need to design a truck fleet monitoring system and make a prototype of it during my traineeship this year.
I've been looking into the different buse networks that are already implemented in trucks nowadays notably the famous OBD II. 
I wonder if it is possible, if I want to add new sensors to the trucks, to implement them within the already existing buses (CAN or other)? otherwise what is the best way to communicate both with the OBD system in the truck and the multiple sensors I might add to the truck? Finally can I make my own CAN buse system in the truck in addition to the one already in it?

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to maintenance or repair.

Comment: Have you considered that a better use of your time would be to evaluate ready-made solutions for fleet management rather than trying to design one?  If nothing else, it's a good first step to designing your own if you need something more specialized.

Comment: Well in the country i live in there arent many of these solutions and whats available is apparently too costly. How can I evaluete in depth such existing solutions and their architecture ?

Comment: What exactly do you need to pull from the vehicles? GPS? Mileage? I'd imagine any preexisting solution either adds a telematics module to the network if it didn't already have one or is using an OE module. How large is this fleet? What are the makes? Do they already have a telematics module? Do you have the software to pull data from it? Do you have to code it from scratch? I think, either way it's going to cost more to develop a robust system than it would be to use a preexisting solution. And you should look at what you actually have to work with before jumping into design.